# Find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers such that $\sum a_n$ converges but $\prod (1+ a_n)$ diverges.

Tags: analysis

Find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers such that $\sum a_n$ converges but $\prod (1+ a_n)$  diverges.

The converse is trivial, just make all the $a_n=-1$.

Comment: Should that be $\prod(1+a_n)$ in the title?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yup, thanks!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119140/proof-of-a-theorem-of-cauchys-on-the-convergence-of-an-infinite-product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not hard to show that if each $|a_n| < 1$ then $\prod_n(1 + a_n)$ converges to a nonzero value iff $\sum_n \log(1 + a_n)$ does (take logarithms of the partial products). If $a_n \rightarrow 0$ then for $n$ large enough, by Taylor expanding the log you have for example
$$ a_n -a_n^2  < \log(1 + a_n) < a_n - {a_n^2 \over 4}$$
So if you take $a_n = (-1)^n{1 \over \sqrt{n}}$, even though $\sum {a_n}$ converges (it's a decreasing alternating series), the sum of the logarithms will diverge since $a_n^2 = {1 \over n}$. So the product will diverge as well.

Comment: Hello, first of $a_n-a_n^2 \log(1+a_n)$ is only true for $a_n >0$ which is not our case if we take an alternating series. Also, isn't it difficult to show that $\sum (-1)^n\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-1/n$ diverges.

Comment: @jake $\log(1 + a_n) = a_n - {a_n^2 \over 2} + o(a_n^2)$ regardless if $a_n$ is positive. And yes, that sum diverges to $-\infty$, that's the point. So the product goes to zero. (It will never go to infinity).

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand, should it be $log(1+a_n)=a_n-\frac{a_n}2+o(a_n^3)$ where $o(a_n^3)$ will be negative if $a_n^3$ is negative so the inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: Also I still don't see how you conclude that $\sum (-1)^n\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1n$ diverges. Every convergence test I've done is inconclusive.

Comment: @Zarrax The product can still converge to zero right?? I computed a bit using SageMath and found that the above product goes close to zero as $n$ becomes large. So I don' t see how your answer is complete.

Comment: @S.SundaraNarasimhan The usual definition of convergence for an infinite product requires the limit to be nonzero.

Comment: @Zarrax If that is the case it is OK, also I'm curious if there are any such sequences that don't converge to any number.

Comment: For simplicity assume each $|a_n| < 1$. Because of the inequality  $ a_n -a_n^2  < \log(1 + a_n) < a_n - {a_n^2 \over 4}$, when $\sum_n a_n$ converges the sum of the $ \log(1 + a_n) $ either converges to a finite number (if $\sum_n a_n^2$ is finite) or equals $-\infty$ (if $\sum_n a_n^2$ is infinite) . In the first case the product converges to a nonzero number and in the second case it goes to zero. But always one of the two cases will hold.

Comment: The inequality a-a^2<log(1+a) does not hold for |a|<1. For example for a=1/2, we have a-a^2=1/4, but log(3/2)=0.176091...

Taking |a| smaller doesn't help either, as can be seen by graphing log(1+x)-x+x^2

Comment: @TheEmptyFunction I should have said for sufficiently small $|a|$. If you graph $\log(1 + x) - x + x^2$ on say $[-0.1,0.1]$, then you can see the function is positive.

Comment: Ah, whoops! The graphing software I was using interprets log as the base 10 logarithm. That's why the inequality wasn't holding