# Convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+a_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, infinite-product

The question is motivated by the following exercise in complex analysis:

> Let $\{a_n\}\subset{\Bbb C}$ such that $a_n\neq-1$ for all $n$. Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2$ converges, then the product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+a_n)$ converges to a non-zero limit if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

One can get a proof by using $|a_n|^2$ to bound $|\log(1+a_n)-a_n|$.

Here is my **question**: is the **converse** of this statement also true?

> If "the product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+a_n)$ converges to a non-zero limit if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges", then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2$ converges.

Comment: So you mean in particular: if they both diverge, then $\sum |a_n|^2$ converges?

Comment: @GEdgar, I think your version might be the right one to ask. I just took the converse of the statement in the exercise.

Comment: The original statement deals with convergence/divergence of $\sum|a_n|^2$, $\prod(1+a_n)$ and $\sum a_n$ and says that the combinations con/div/con and con/con/div are not possible (but con/con/con and con/div/div are). What is *your* question? We are only left with whether or not the other four combinations are possible: div/div/div (trivially yes), div/con/div (I'm quite sure), div/div/con (I'm quite sure), div/con/con (I'm quite sure).

Comment: A real analysis version: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119140/proof-of-a-theorem-of-cauchys-on-the-convergence-of-an-infinite-product

Comment: @GEdgar, On a second thought, I think what I'm asking is slightly different from your question: The converse of $r\to (p\leftrightarrow q)$ is $(q\leftrightarrow p)\to r$.

Answer (score 3):

I shall try to give examples where $\sum|a_n|^2$ is divergent and all possible combinations of convergence/divergence for $\prod(1+a_n)$ and $\sum a_n$.

Let $a_{2n}=\frac1{\sqrt n}$ and $a_{2n+1}=\frac1{1+a_{2n}}-1=-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt n}$. Then $(1+a_{2n})(1+a_{2n+1})= 1$, hence the product converges. But $a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}=\frac1{n+\sqrt n}>\frac1{2n}$, hence $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Let $a_{2n}=\frac1{\sqrt n}$ and $a_{2n+1}=-\frac1{\sqrt n}$. Then $a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}=0$, hence $\sum a_n$ converges. But $(1+a_{2n})(1+a_{2n+1})=1-\frac1n$; the $\log$ of this is $\sim -\frac1n$, hence $\sum \log(1+a_n)$ and also $\prod(1+a_n)$ diverges.

Let $a_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}$. Then $\prod(1+a_n)$ and $\sum a_n$ diverge.

It *almost* looks as if it is not possible to have both $\prod(1+a_n)$ and $\sum a_n$ convergent if $\sum |a_n|^2$ diverges because $\ln(1+a_n) = a_n-\frac12a_n^2\pm\ldots$, but here we go:
If $n=4k+r$ with $r\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, let $a_n = \frac{i^r}{\sqrt k}$. Then the product of four such consecutive terms is $(1+\frac1{\sqrt k})(1+\frac i{\sqrt k})(1-\frac1{\sqrt k})(1-\frac i{\sqrt k})=1-\frac1{k^2}$, hence the log of these is $\sim -\frac1{k^2}$ and the product converges. The sum also converges (to $0$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For the first one, $\prod_{n=1}^N a_n=1$ when $N$ is even and $\prod_{n=1}^N a_n=-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{N}}$ when $N$ is odd. Could you show that why this converges?

Comment: in your second example $\sum \log(1+a_n)$ will diverge to $-\infty$ that implies $\prod (1+a_n)$ converge to 0 right?

Answer (score 1):

The convergence of $\Pi_{n=0}^\infty(1+a_n)$ is equivalent to that of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\ln(1+a_n)$. Note 
$$ \ln(1+x)=x-\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(|x|^3). $$
So
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\ln(1+a_n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n-\frac{1}{2}a_n^2+O(|a_n|^3))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^2+\sum_{n=0}^\infty O(|a_n|^3).$$
Note the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_n|^2$ implies the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^2$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty O(|a_n|^3)$. Thus the product $\Pi_{n=0}^\infty(1+a_n)$ converges to a non-zero limit if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Comment: This is the problem in the exercise, not the converse he asks about.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that convergence/divergence of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n)$ is equivalent to convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. (For simplicity's sake, let us assume $a_n \neq -1$ for all $n$, so that we don't trivially get a product of zero.) It is self-evident that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \text{ and } \prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{a_n} = e^{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n}$$

either both converge, or both diverge. So we can rephrase OP's question as:

"Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that convergence/divergence of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n)$ is equivalent to convergence/divergence of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{a_n}$. Must $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ converge absolutely?"

---

---

**Lemma:** In order for convergence/divergence of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n)$ to be equivalent to convergence/divergence of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{a_n}$, then

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n) e^{-a_n}$$

must converge.

*Proof of lemma:* We need to show that if one of these products diverges but the other one converges, then $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n) e^{-a_n}$ diverges.

- *Case 1:* $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n)$ diverges but $\prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{a_n} \rightarrow P \neq 0$. Then

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{n=1}^N (1 + a_n) e^{-a_n} = \frac{1}{P} \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{n=1}^N (1 + a_n),$$

and by hypothesis $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{n=1}^N (1 + a_n)$ DNE, so neither does $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{n=1}^N (1 + a_n) e^{-a_n}$.

- *Case 2:* $\prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{a_n}$ diverges but $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n)$ converges to a nonzero limit. The same idea as in Case 1 works to show that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{n=1}^N (1 + a_n) e^{-a_n}$ DNE.

---

---

Armed with our lemma, it is now easy to find examples of sequences $\{ a_n \}$ for which $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n) e^{-a_n}$ converges, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2$ is divergent.

For instance, if we pick $a_n = \frac{i^n}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1}$ diverges. However:

- Since

$$(1 + a_n) e^{-a_n} = 1 - a_n^2/2 + \Theta(a_n^3),$$

and:

- For this sequence, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges, while $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^3$ converges absolutely because $|a_n^3| = n^{-3/2}$,

this is enough to show that

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n) e^{-a_n} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty [1 - a_n^2/2 + \Theta(a_n^3)]$$

converges, since the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty -a_n^2/2 + \Theta(a_n^3)$$

converges and the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty [-a_n^2/2 + \Theta(a_n^3)]^2$$

converges absolutely: $[a_n^2/2 + \Theta(a_n^3)]^2 = \Theta(n^{-2})$.

---

---

**However:** if the $\{ a_n \}$ are restricted to be *real* numbers, then it **does** become true that "convergence/divergence of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n)$ is equivalent to convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ *only if* $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ converges".

The only interesting case is when $a_n \rightarrow 0$, so making the assumption $a_n \rightarrow 0$, we will eventually have, for any $\epsilon > 0$,

$$1 - (1 + \epsilon)a_n^2/2 \leq (1 + a_n) e^{-a_n} \leq 1 - (1-\epsilon)a_n^2/2.$$

But $(1 \pm \epsilon)a_n^2/2$ is always positive for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, since $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, and we know that for a positive sequence $p_n \geq 0$,

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - p_n) \text{ converges iff } \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n \text{ does.}$$

Fix $\epsilon$ and let $N$ be large enough so that for all $n \geq N$,

$$1 - (1+\epsilon)a_n^2/2 \leq (1 + a_n) e^{-a_n} \leq 1 - (1-\epsilon)a_n^2/2.$$

Then

$$\prod_{n=N}^\infty [1 - (1+\epsilon)a_n^2/2] \leq \prod_{n=N}^\infty (1 + a_n) e^{-a_n} \leq \prod_{n=N}^\infty [1 - (1-\epsilon)a_n^2/2],$$

so the middle product converges iff the left-hand product converges iff the right-hand product converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ converges. This proves OP's hypothesis for sequences $\{ a_n \}$ of real numbers.