# Is $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

The question is motivated by the following exercise:

> Find an example of a sequence of complex numbers $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum a_n$ converges but $\prod(1+a_n)$ diverges.

A necessary condition for $\{a_n\}$ is that $\sum|a_n|^2$ must diverges according to the exercise I referred to in a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/362899/9464). (This would be also sufficient if the answer to that question is yes.)

My first **question**:

> Is $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$ convergent? (I don't see a convergence test which would immediately help.)

We would have an example for the exercise above if the answer is no. Can one come up with another example?

Comment: Expand taylor series of log to two terms + an error term, what can you see?

Comment: Maybe this question is obsolete by my answer to the other question ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\log\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\right)$$
and since the series $\displaystyle\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_n \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$ are convergent and the series $\displaystyle\sum_n\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent then the given series is divergent.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not convinced by your use of big O notation here. Could you elaborate the second half of your argument? I don't see why this is immediately right when one just plugs the first formula to the infinite sum.

Comment: @Jack Since the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent then by comparaison test the series $\sum_n O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ is also convergent. Now suppose that we have $u_n=v_n+w_n$ where the series $\sum_n v_n$ is convergent and $\sum_n w_n$ is divergent, what about $\sum_n u_n$?

Comment: $x_n=O(1/n^2)$ means there's $M>0$ such that $|x_n|\leq M\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane, Should $O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ be $O(\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}})$ instead?

Comment: @Jack you're right thanks.