# If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^∞|a_n|^2$ converges, then $\prod\limits_{n=1}^∞(1+a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^∞a_n$ converges.

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

> If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^2$ converges, then $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

My attempt is to use the Cauchy citerion, given $m>n$, $$\left|\prod_{i=1}^{m}(1+a_i)-\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+a_i)\right|=\left|\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+a_i)\left[\prod_{i=n+1}^{m}(1+a_i)-1\right]\right|\\
=\left|\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+a_i)\right|\left|\prod_{i=n+1}^{m}(1+a_i)-1\right|,\\
\left|\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+a_i)\right| \leqslant \prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+|a_i|),$$ then how to proceed?

Comment: Hint: try expressing the mulitplication as an infinite sum plus an infinite multiplication.

Comment: This seems related: [Convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+a_n)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362899/convergence-of-prod-n-1-infty1a-n). Perhaps some of other questions tagged [infinite-product+complex-analysis](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-product+complex-analysis) might be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

We first assume that $a_n\in \mathbb{R}$.

Note that since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ converges, then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$.  There exists, therefore, a number $N$ so that $1+a_n>0$ whenever $n>N$.

Applying the Mean Value Theorem, it is straightforward to show that

$$x-\frac12x^2+\frac13x^3\le \log(1+x)\le x \tag 1$$

Applying $(1)$, we have for $n>N$

$$a_n-\frac12 a_n^2+\frac13 a_n^3 \le \log(1+a_n)\le a_n\le \frac12 a_n^2-\frac13a_n^3+\log(1+a_n) \tag 2$$
Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ converges, then so does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^3$.  From $(2)$, it is easy to see that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Finally, we note that for $n>N$

$$\prod_{n=N}^\infty (1+a_n)=e^{\sum_{n=N}^\infty \log(1+a_n)} \tag 3$$

whence we arrive at the coveted result!

---

If $a_n\in \mathbb{C}$, and if $n$ is so large that $\text{Re}(1+a_n)> 0$, then $\log(1+a_n)$ can be expanded as

$$\log(1+a_n)=a_n-\frac12 a_n^2+O(a_n^3)$$

where we are free to choose to use the principal branch of the logarithm function to define $\log(1+a_n)$.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ converges, then so does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^3$.

Now we can proceed along similar lines as to the proof for real-valued $a_n$.  The details are left as an exercise.

Comment: Isn't the first part true only, if $a_n>0$?

Comment: This inequality $1-\frac12x^2\le \log(1+x)\le x \tag 1$ fails for values of $x$ near 0

Comment: Good catch.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\gt-1$, writing $x-\log(1+x)=\int_0^x\frac{t}{1+t}\,\mathrm{d}t$, it follows that
$$
0\le x-\log(1+x)\le\frac{\frac12x^2}{\min(1,1+x)}\tag1
$$
Thus, for $|x|\le\frac12$, we have
$$
|\,x-\log(1+x)\,|\le x^2\tag2
$$
If either $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ or $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\log(1+a_n)$ converges, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Thus, there is an $N$ so that $n\ge N\implies|a_n|\le\frac12$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\left|\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log(1+a_n)\,\right|\\
&\le\left|\,\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\log(1+a_n)\,\right|+\left|\,\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n-\sum_{n=N}^\infty\log(1+a_n)\,\right|\tag{3a}\\
&\le\left|\,\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\log(1+a_n)\,\right|+\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n^2\tag{3b}\\[9pt]
&\lt\infty\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: triangle inequality
$\text{(3b)}$: apply $(2)$
$\text{(3c)}$: the sum of two finite sums is finite

Comment: From (3a) to (3b), I think during the argument of second term, you used  $\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n-\sum_{n=N}^\infty \log(1+a_n)\right|\leq \left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n -\log(1+a_n)\right|$. But we don't know the convergence of $\sum a_n$ or $\sum \log(1+a_n)$ depending on the assumption. How do you know $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n -\sum_{n=N}^\infty\log(1+a_n) = \sum_{n=N}^\infty (a_n - \log(1+a_n))$?

Comment: Note that it is stated that "If either $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ or $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\log(1+a_n)$ converges..." That is, we assume that one converges and $(3)$ shows that the other converges.

Comment: I'm only talking about $\sum_{n=N}^\infty$ part of (3a). The equality I wrote in the comment holds if both $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=N}^\infty\log(1+a_n)$ converges, doesn't it?

Comment: Suppose that $\sum\limits_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ converges and  $\sum\limits_{n=N}^\infty a_n^2$ converges, then $(2)$ shows that $\sum\limits_{n=N}^\infty\log(1+a_n)$ converges. Suppose that $\sum\limits_{n=N}^\infty\log(1+a_n)$ and $\sum\limits_{n=N}^\infty a_n^2$ converges, then $(2)$ shows that $\sum\limits_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ converges. This means that if $\sum\limits_{n=N}^\infty a_n^2$ converges, $\sum\limits_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ converges iff $\sum\limits_{n=N}^\infty\log(1+a_n)$ converges.